# background image not centering / keeps repeating

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently trying to create a test site just to practice, and for one my background image will not center/ and keeps repeating whenever I try to make it responsive. Also the whole image is not present within the browser. Any solution would be helpful.

I tried 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

and it's still not working.

```css
body {
    font-family: Nunito;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517048676732-d65bc937f952?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1005f3d059e15847f5b8e818aafe7b51&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
    color: #C7DB8A;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align-last: center;
    padding-top: 15%;
}

.jumbotron p {
    color: #5E9589;
}
```

```html
<!--lorem: ctrl+shift+L -->
<!--hr styles-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>asdfs Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/home.js"></script>

    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fa-svg-with-js.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <!--nav-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ABXCH</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fas fa-home"></i>
                        Home
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
                        About
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <i class="far fa-handshake"></i>
                        Contact
                        </a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
                        Login
                        </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--jumbo-->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>asdfas</h1>
                    <p>Your Online Insurance Sales Office</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with `background-repeat` but you are facing a **background propagation**. As you can see in the below screenshoot, your `body` element is not taking full height of the screen and there is some special rules with background when we have such situation:

[image]

As you can read in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds):

> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element or an XHTML
>   html element [HTML]: if **the computed value of background-image on the**
>   **root element** is **none** and its **background-color** is **transparent**, user
>   agents must instead **propagate the computed values of the background**
>   **properties from that element’s first HTML BODY** or XHTML body child
>   element. The used values of that BODY element’s background properties
>   are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if
>   they were specified on the root element. It is recommended that
>   authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the BODY
>   element rather than the HTML element.

This means that the background is propagated **to cover the area** not covered by the `body` and thus you have the reapeted background. To avoid such behavior you can insure that the body takes full screen height by adding `min-height:100vh` or apply a `background-color` to the `html` element and keep the image to cover only the content part:

```css
html {
  background:white;
}

body {
    font-family: Nunito;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517048676732-d65bc937f952?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1005f3d059e15847f5b8e818aafe7b51&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
    color: #C7DB8A;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align-last: center;
    padding-top: 15%;
}

.jumbotron p {
    color: #5E9589;
}
```

```html
<!--lorem: ctrl+shift+L -->
<!--hr styles-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>asdfs Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/home.js"></script>

    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fa-svg-with-js.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <!--nav-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ABXCH</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fas fa-home"></i>
                        Home
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
                        About
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <i class="far fa-handshake"></i>
                        Contact
                        </a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
                        Login
                        </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--jumbo-->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>asdfas</h1>
                    <p>Your Online Insurance Sales Office</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

---

Some related links for more informations:

[What's the meaning of "propagated to the viewport" in the CSS spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886274/whats-the-meaning-of-propagated-to-the-viewport-in-the-css-spec)

[Applying a background to <html> and/or <body>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body)

https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/

Answer (score 0):

Because you not set the `background-repeat:no-repeat;` try following code:

```
body {
font-family: Nunito;
background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517048676732-d65bc937f952?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1005f3d059e15847f5b8e818aafe7b51&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat:no-repeat; // Added
min-height:100vh; // Added for ensure capture window size
}
```

Comment: ya I've tried background no repeat also, I think the min-height:100vh; was what I was looking for thanks

Comment: @hellothere this is wrong and it has nothing to do with background-repeat ... the min-height fixed this for another reason, check my answer for more information

Answer (score -1):

Just put **background-repeat: no-repeat** and **background-size: cover** . It will work

```
background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x300);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```