# why Scroll behaviour doesn't work when it is applied to the body tag?

Tags: css, scroll

I have some sections linked to some a tags.
i tried scroll behaviour : smooth on body : it didn't worrk.
i applied it to HTML : It worked.
So what am i missing ? what is the diference between the two ?

```
 body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

the code is [here](https://codepen.io/3aluw/pen/bGoaprQ)

Comment: That is because the `<html>` element is the default scrolling element, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @Terry , is it the case for scroll-snap ?, I faced the same problem, it works with html not with body,

Comment: Yes since it’s also a scroll-related property. It only works on scrolling elements.

Comment: So that means if i wanted to apply this properties on body (or other element) I need to add overflow : scroll .

Comment: No. The html element will scroll by default when it overflows. But for other elements yes, you will need something like `overflow-y: auto` (don’t use `scroll` because that’ll force a scrollbar even when content is not overflowing)

Comment: what does "default scrolling element" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In documentation from Mozilla about scroll-behavior:

> This property specified on the body element will not propagate to the viewport.

Full documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

And more about propagation(last sentence of submitted answer):
[What's the meaning of "propagated to the viewport" in the CSS spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886274/whats-the-meaning-of-propagated-to-the-viewport-in-the-css-spec#answer-41886687)

Comment: i want to kill myself